# read csv file saved in static folder

Tags: django

I have some javascript in index.html that visualizes data stored in population.csv. But nothing is displayed. My directory and the javascript code is listed below. I think I need to change the directory to reach the population.csv but what I have tried hasn't worked. I have tried /static/population.csv.

- examplebi

  - examplebi
  - static

    - population.csv
  - templates

    - index.html
  - visualize

```
d3.csv("population.csv", function(error, data) {
  // Convert strings to numbers.
  data.forEach(function(d) {
    d.people = +d.people;
    d.year = +d.year;
    d.age = +d.age;
  });
```